# Having trouble checking for newline when reading file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write a program to read a file of an unknown size / line size but I'm having some issues detecting the new line character.

When I run the program, it never reaches the end of the line point within the while loop in `readFile` and will just run constantly. If I run print each character, it prints out some unknown char.

I've tried setting `ch` to be an int value and typecasting to char for `\n` comparison. It's not reaching the `EOF` condition either so I'm not sure what is going on.

code:

```
void readFile(FILE* file)
{
    int endOfFile = 0;
    while (endOfFile != 1)
    {
        endOfFile = readLine(file);
        printf("%d\n", endOfFile);
    }
}

int readLine(FILE* file)
{
    static int maxSize = LINE_SIZE;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    int endOfFile = 0;
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * maxSize);
    char ch;

    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if ((ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n'))
        {
            buffer[currentIndex] = (char) ch;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }

        if (currentIndex == maxSize)
        {
            printf("Reallocating string buffer");
            maxSize *= 2;
            buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, maxSize);
        }
    } while ((ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n'));

    if (ch == EOF)
    {
        endOfFile = 1;
    }

    parseLine(buffer);
    free(buffer);

    return endOfFile;
}
```

If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated because I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n')
```

This is always true.

You want an `&&` (AND) here, both in your `if` and `while`, otherwise it will never stop.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. I'll mark as correct after time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this boilerplate standard construct

```
int ch;  /* important, EOF is -1, not in the range 0-255 */
FILE *fp;

/* double brackets prevent warnings about assignment in if */
while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
  /* we now have a valid character */

  /* usually */
  if(ch == endofinputIlike)
    break; 
}
/* here you have either read all the input up to what you like
  or skip because of EOF. usually you will set N or something, 
  or if N == 0 it was EOF, or we can test ch for EOF */
```

Generally assignment in if is a bad idea, but this particular snippet is so idiomatic that every experienced C programmer will instantly recognise it.